# How to compile SCIP to get the binary package like the one provided on the SCIP web (Windows)

Tags: c++, c, window, scip

I know there are a lot posts about how to compile SCIP, I cannot find one to answer my following question well.

For Windows, SCIP main webpage provides several pre-compiled binary as follows:

=========================================================================

> Windows/PC, 64bit, msvc 12.0: dynamically linked to SoPlex 2.2.0,
>   Zimpl 3.3.3, Ipopt 3.12.3, CppAD 20140000.1, MPIR 2.6.0, zlib 1.2.5
>   [requires the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages]
>
> Windows/PC, 64bit, msvc 12.0: statically linked to SoPlex 2.2.0,
>   Zimpl 3.3.3, Ipopt 3.12.3, CppAD 20140000.1, MPIR 2.6.0, zlib 1.2.5
>   [requires the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages]

=========================================================================

However there is no information about how can we achieve this. I have read the installation file, and have no idea.
I wonder how can I compile such a binary, just like the above one, except that CPLEX will be the LP solver? Is there any guide to do this? 
(PS: The question is also asked through the SCIP mailing list)

Thanks a lot!
Feng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve a binary (including CPLEX) on Windows is to use Cygwin or MinGW. With those two environments you can compile SCIP with make LPS=cpx (first, you have to link to CPLEX).

To obtain the .dll file you will have to use the Visual Studio Compiler and the Makefile.nmake which is currently missing in the distribution. We will add the file as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I checked previous distributions of SCIP, and did not find the "Makefile.nmake" file. I wonder in which version i can use this file?